# mind mapping controls for Web Application (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, mindmapping

I was wondering if anyone may know of any third party controls that can be purchased to perform mind mapping capabilities?  My goal is to have the ability to wire up "canned up" controls.  The controls should give a user an ability to drag and drop boxes and circles and make connections accordingly and automatically.  However, the connections and the data in boxes and circles would be persisted on a SQL database via a .NET web application.

I have looked at the links below and added some notes.  Most them seem to be available to purchase as individual licenses versus for a web server environment.

Please keep in mind that I have already taken the route to start developing my own mind mapping controls via JQUERY for an ASP.NET application but I'm weighing out my options due to time constraints.

Bubbl – can’t seem to purchase the controls for a web application.
https://bubbl.us/

Graph Visualization – seems like a desktop application with the ability to purchase individual licenses.
http://www.graphviz.org/

Mindjet - seem like a desktop application with the ability to purchase individual licenses.
http://info.mindjet.com/conceptmapping.html?cmpg=Americas_-_Google_US_CN_Mapping&gclid=CMKI_IqOs6kCFQQbKgodmCCZLg

SmartDraw seem like a desktop application with the ability to purchase individual licenses.
http://www.smartdraw.com/product/features/

Gallery – Can’t seem to find a way to purchase the any of the products and don’t know if the controls are for a web application.
http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago I tried the Bookbar open source mind mapping tool and it seemed pretty decent:
http://bookvar.codeplex.com/. You may want to play with it, too.

Comment: thanks so much I think this will get me continue to build on my own.  still hoping to find something I can pull out of the box and just do simple binds to the correct data.